# Redirect subdir with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, parameters

My first question here! :) Hello!

I have some trouble with .htaccess.

1. http://www.domain.com/subdir/?parameter=example works.
2. http://www.domain.com/subdir/example doesn't work.

When i try this:

```
RewriteBase /subdir
RewriteRule ^index.php - [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?i=$1 [R,L]
```

i get an 404.shtml error like http:// www.domain.com/subdir/index.php?i=404.shtml

Also the wp-admin(http:// www.domain.com/wp-admin/) redirects to the subdir with 404.shtml. How do i get the url like http:// www.domain.com/subdir/example/

Can anyone help me?? Thnx in advanced!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is a WordPress installation (based on the mention of 'wp-admin'), you want the following

Just use the WordPress standard, put this .htaccess into the root folder

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /subdir/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /subdir/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Go to Settings and change Site address (URL) under General Settings to `http://www.domain.com/subdir/`

Put the following `index.php` into the root folder

```
<?php

    define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);

    /** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
    require('./subdir/wp-blog-header.php');
?>
```

Go to Settings > Permalinks and change the permalink structure to whatever you need

p.s. to access wp-admin you need to navigate to `http://www.domain.com/subdir/wp-admin/`

more info here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress#Giving_WordPress_its_Own_Directory_While_Leaving_the_WordPress_Index_File_in_the_Root_Directory

Comment: Thnx, but this is not the right solution. Wordpress is installed in the root..

It is another php file apart from wordpress!

Comment: RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ /subdir/index.php?i=$1 [L] work when your URL is http://www.domain.com/subdir/example / but not with the latest /.. How can i fix this?

Comment: @user1263678 to allow for trailing / just change `/$` to something like `[/]?$`